# How can I pass arbitrary user-defined values into a CarrierWave image processor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, rmagick

So I'm working on a rails 3.2 app where I have a CarrierWave uploader; which I use to upload images, and split crop them into a few different sizes - pretty standard stuff.

What I would like to do is composite a new image on top of the image being uploaded, which is also pretty straight forward. (very commonly done for watermarking). The difference is that instead of having static values for positioning the composited image, I need them to be dynamic.

The thing I'm having trouble with is figuring out how to pass dynamic user-defined positional arguments into my carrierwave processor in the 'version' block.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can store the value into model instance

then, in the process method to get it by model attr

```
# model class
# define attr_accessor coords
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :coords
  mount_uploader :icon, AvatarUploader
end



# controller
# pass the params to @user.coords
def crop_icon
  @user.coords = params[:coords]
  @user.icon = params[:icon]
  @user.save
end



# Uploader
# the model in the function is same as @user in controll,
# and can be invoked inside of process method 
 def crop_area
    manipulate! do |img|
      unless model.coords.nil?
        coords = JSON.parse(model.coords)
        img.crop("#{coords['w']}x#{coords['h']}+#{coords['x']}+#{coords['y']}")
      end
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 13):

A little gotcha for rails 4: The other user options must be permitted in strong params **before** the file input param to properly be updated first and accessible via the Uploader.

Comment: This is the most goddamn evil bug I've ever encountered. Fortunately, upon encountering it the second time, I had already upvoted your answer.

Comment: Just ran into this issue also. I'm surprised there aren't more up votes. Anyone trying to access virtual attributes on a model where those attributes are permitted after the uploaded file attribute will run into this.

Comment: Thank you very much for this notice! I spent more than one hour trying to transmit my cropping parameters to the uploader on Rails 5. And indeed, I had in my controller: params.permit(:file, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h) instead of params.permit(:crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h, :file). As soon as I switched it worked perfectly. I did not find this such useful information anywhere else.

Comment: how about with strong params with merge, I have try but value of attribute merged still nil when access in uploader.

Comment: @Georgemayer, great find! This is the only place I've seen the suggestion. Kept me scratching my head for hours. I am compelled to write up a `gist` to show the proper model, controller and uploader code as I am sure we're not the only ones who require passing in `attr_accessors` from a form into the uploader.  Upvoted! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. I called the Uploaders store method directly but it only accepts one parameter and that is file. I also needed to pass some id for storing the files in particular directory. This is what I ended up doing and was fairly simple:

I defined uploader instance variable as and a class method to set the value

```
class DocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    attr_accessor :cid

    def set_id id
        self.cid = id
    end
    ...
    def your_method
        my_id = self.cid
    end

end
```

Then in the controller action I did this:

```
uploader = DocumentUploader.new
uploader.set_id(id)
uploader.store!(my_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Digging this out.

You can pass arguments like this

```ruby
process do_stuff: ["foo", "bar"]

def do_stuff(arg_foo, arg_bar)
  arg_foo == "foo" # => true
  arg_bar == "bar" # => true
end
```

IMHO it's better than polluting model with dummy instance variables.